# Sorting a Query in Solrj with whitespace

Tags: solr, solrj

I'm using solr querying some documents. In this one case I don't want to order the results by relevance, I want them to be sorted by title. I've done the following in solrj:

```
//sort by title
setSortField("title", SolrQuery.ORDER.asc)
```

This works fine, when there are no whitespaces or slashes in the titles of the documents. When I have 4 documents, the title values are ordered like that:

```
"A"
"B"
"C"
"B D"
```

It seems to me, that Solr starts ordering from a field after the first whitespace in it.
Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: Are you using string or text? Indexed and/or stored? Dont want to be rude, but is your example **literally** true; does `B D` **literally** come after `C`? Else please post some real examples.

Comment: The described behaviour is probably due to your indexing chain. It all depends on what tokenizer and filters you use for the title field. In fact, sorting is made with indexed values, which differ from what you see in the results (stored content).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example I described was a constructed one, but I tested it now also with the given example and there was the same behaviour.

I use the following config for the field:

```
<fieldType name="textgen" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
   <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" enablePositionIncrements="true" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" splitOnCaseChange="0" catenateAll="0" catenateNumbers="1" catenateWords="1" generateNumberParts="1" generateWordParts="1"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
   </analyzer>
   <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" expand="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" enablePositionIncrements="true" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" splitOnCaseChange="0" catenateAll="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateWords="0" generateNumberParts="1" generateWordParts="1"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
   </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Thanks for your replies.

Comment: make another copy of this field with field type  using keyword tokenizer instead of whitespace tokenizer ....

Comment: thanks for your reply, the keywordtokenizer changed the order but it was still not ordered literally correct. I will try to recreate the error with the basic configuration solr comes with.

Answer (score 0):

please find the field type to create

```
{
  "add-field-type" : {
     "name":"master_keyword_sort",
     "class":"solr.TextField",
     "positionIncrementGap":"100",
     "analyzer" : {
         "tokenizer":{ 
           "class":"solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" },
        "filters":[{
           "class":"solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory",
           "pattern":"([^A-Za-z0-9])",
           "replacement":"" ,"replace":"all"},
           {
           "class":"solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"
           }]}}
}
```